# Vertically aligning q tags

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

I'm currently trying to vertically align a q tag in my CSS, but for some reason, the quotation marks don't also get aligned, creating a problem. Here is the relevant part of the code in question:

```
q {
   vertical-align: top;
}
```

[Here is an image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mv5AZ.png) of the problem. I don't know if this is some sort of complicated issue involving multiple parts interacting, but if so, here is my [html](http://pastebin.com/fFKe5Ldj) and [css](http://pastebin.com/Tm3GjFzN) files.

Comment: I don't know if this is getting downvoted because this page is a stock web programming homework, but to clarify, using online resources, like Stack Overflow, is both allowed and accepted where I go to school.

Comment: I presume the downvote is because you should paste your minimal HTML and CSS to re-create your problem. But your image is displaying more than a q tag.

Comment: Yup - check out [MCVE]. Stack Overflow sets the bar reasonably high in terms of quality of questions - make it as easy as possible for potential answerers and you're likely to get a much better reaction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The vertical-align property only applies to:

> inline-level and 'table-cell' elements

See this [link](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#propdef-vertical-align).

try

```
q {
   display: inline;
   vertical-align: top;
}
```

Comment: So, the stuff inside of q are inline, however, the quotation marks it creates aren't inline? If so, that explains why it isn't working. Unfortunately, the display inline thing isn't fixing the issue.

Comment: You have the code already, could you create a jsfiddle or code pen example? that way I can easily fork it and help you figure it out

Comment: Alright, I created a copy [here](https://jsfiddle.net/MegaZerox/8fgkc8z4/). It  doesn't have the images, but they aren't important, as the quotation tags inside the p tags are the ones with issues.

Comment: ok, And what you want is the quotes aligned right?

Comment: Yes. I have a work around solution from the other answer to the question, but I want to know how to do it properly for the future.

Comment: I think the 'work around' is the way, I can think of many. Let me explain you the problem: <q> gets rendered with pseudoelements, the quotations are actually q:before and q:after. And pseudo elements dont have the same rules as elements. So it can be done, but I couldnt do it in 10 minuts, I would just use a div with a class or something with a class and write the quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Try using float left on the image instead.

```css
img {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<p class="quote">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" alt="Fresh" />
  <q>TMNT is a fun, action-filled adventure that will satisfy longtime fans and generate a legion of new ones.</q>
</p>
```

Comment: This works, but I'd still love to find a way to circumvent that weird quotation thing for future use. I'd like to be able to vertically align my entire q tags.